# WordPress query not finding data from custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field group set for the homepage (found under pages). I'm trying to extract that data like so:

***home.php***

```
// query to fetch data from page
$argsOverview = array('post_type' => 'pages' );
$getOverviewPage = new WP_Query($argsOverview);

if ($getOverviewPage->have_posts() ) {

            tp_get_part( 'templates/snippets/section-two-overview.php',
                array(
                    'overviewHeading'          => get_field('overview_heading'),
                    'overviewSubheading'       => get_field('overview_subheading'),
                    'overviewText'             => get_field('overview_text'),
                    'overviewBackground'       => get_field('background_color'),
                    )
                );

            echo $overviewHeading;
} else {
    echo "test";
}
```

***section-two-overview.php***

```
<div class="overview-container" style="background-color: <?php echo $overviewBackground; ?>">
        <div class="overview-wrapper">
            <p>test</p>
            <h3><?php echo $overviewHeading; ?></h3>
            <h1><?php echo $overvewSubheading; ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $overviewText; ?></p>
        </div> 
</div>
```

However, it not displaying the content from *section-two-overview.php*? *`tp_get_part()`* is a custom function which works elsewhere. But when pulling data from pages and not custom post types, it doesn't execute.

Currently, it shows the `echo "test"`, meaning the *if* failed, unsure why?

Comment: can you post a var_dump/print_r/whatever of what is in $getOverviewPage just prior to your if statement?

Comment: @LukeG. Doing 'var_dump($getOverviewPage);' returned about 12 lines of text i.e. "object(WP_Query)#1041 (48) { ["query"]=> array(1) { ["post_type"]=> string(5) "pages" }..." Guessing my query is wrong?

Comment: see my answer below, I think you need a singular page and not pages in your query.  Please accept the answer if that fixed it for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try 'post_type' => 'page' in your query and see if it works.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types